# How to derive class name from confusing error message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails app I am getting the following error message:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `foo' for #<#<Class:0x007fbf5d75ecd8>:0x007fbf62684060>)
```

How can I derive the actual class **name** from that?

Comment: Error messages from Rails view can be confusing sometimes. In this case it might be an unnamed class: `a = Class.new; a.inspect #=> "#<Class:0x00...` It is probably easier to grep code changes for the string `foo`.

Comment: What do you need class name for? For finding the origin of the exception, all you need is a stacktrace. Which you also have.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: I need it for debugging purposes. Stacktrace doesn't provide the exact class name here, unfortunately.

Comment: @Tintin81: yeah, you won't get a class name, because there is none. Also, what kind of debugging do you do where you _need_ a class name, in addition to what stacktrace gives you? I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: I guess I'm just desperate to fix this bug. I'll better post the details in another thread.

Comment: @Tintin81 I think the point was that the stacktrace should give you the filename and line number where the exception was raised